# How can i set Header map in case of custom HTTP Request in java?

Tags: java, http, http-headers

I was using java.net.http package to create custom request. i could set additional headers to pass but can't set a header map in the request, is there any way i can do this in this particular way of making http request, or in any other method of making request.

```
HttpRequest.newBuilder()
.uri(URI.create(targetUrl)
.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
.method(myMethod, HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body))
.build();
```

I want to set HeaderMap => **Map<String,List>** just like we are setting a single header above.

It would be great if anyone could help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HttpRequestBuilder` doesn't allow a direct set of the `Map<String, List<String>>` into the headers nor exposes an equivalent of `putAll`.

However, provided you have a `Map<String, List<String>>` called `yourHeaders`, then you can simply do the following:

```
HttpRequest.Builder builder = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .uri(URI.create(targetUrl)
  .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .method(myMethod, HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body));

yourHeaders.forEach((headerKey, headerValues) -> headerValues.forEach(value -> builder.header(headerKey, value)));

return builder.build();
```

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: restricted header name: "content-length"
`
getting above error while putting values just like you did

Comment: Some headers are protected. meaning you can't override them. You should exclude them from your map.

Comment: Where can i get the list of such headers which i can't set/override.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SarthakS simply go where the exception  is thrown and you will see an ALLOWED_HEADERS predicate from which you can get the list.

Comment: Thanks alot for such a clear explanation.

Comment: @SarthakS if it's good for you, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Sorry to ask this again but i am unable to find ALLOWED_HEADERS predicate.

Comment: @SarthakS this is the default that I find in Java 11: `"connection", "content-length", "date", "expect", "from", "host", "upgrade", "via", "warning"`